# How can we convert PGN format to Resource Description Framework (RDF)?

Tags: software, pgn

Is there any parser available in which we take PGN data as input and then convert it to [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) format? Has someone worked on this thing?

Answer (score 4):

I do maintain that converter at UPM. 
You may also want to read the (highly technical) related papers:

- [An Ontology Design Pattern for Chess Games](http://delicias.dia.fi.upm.es/~vrodriguez/pdf/2015.09.wop.pdf)
- [Pattern-Based Linked Data Publication: The Linked Chess Dataset Case](http://delicias.dia.fi.upm.es/~vrodriguez/pdf/2015.10.cold.pdf)

Comment: This is cool, are there any applications?

Comment: Nothing else, besides beautiful browsing of a few hundred of chessplayers and some of their games. Information is taken from Wikipedia. http://salonica.dia.fi.upm.es:8080/rdfchess/resource/chessplayer/Bobby+Fischer

Answer (score 1):

I found this website that seems to do exactly what you are asking, as far as I can tell, it is the only resource available for PGN->RDF conversion.

The website is http://salonica.dia.fi.upm.es:8080/rdfchess/pgn2rdf.html

Sorry for the link-only answer, but it seems to answer the question.

~CSS